# Passed array inconsistent bahevior; C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to learn some basic C++ and the moment I started to think I got a grasp of all those pointers I stumbled across this problem:

```
int sizeOf(string texts[]) {
    return sizeof(texts);
}

int main() {
    string texts[] = {"apple", "banana", "orange", "watermelon"};
    cout << sizeof(texts) << endl;
    cout << sizeOf(texts) << endl;
}
```

and this function returns

```
128
8
```

My question is: what is happening when I pass this array as an argument? Why suddenly C++ forgets that this is an array? I have tried to dereference it inside a method (`return sizeof(*texts)`) but it returned `32` instead which is the size of one string element, not a whole array. Is it possible to do what I want to do? Where am I mistaken?

Comment: The array degrades into a pointer since you don't have a size for it. Use `std::array` in c++ if you want to know the size etc

Comment: Try search "sizeof array parameter" on stackoverflow.com